# Pass Data from ViewController > TabBarController>NavigationController>ViewController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a login screen that goes to a tab bar, which then transitions to a Navigation Controller.  I need to pass the username to the first view controller of the Navigation Controller.  so it goes:

Login Screen -> TabBarController -> NavigationController -> CustomerMainViewController

I have been all over stack overflow and implemented the following code which seems to be the consensus:

```
//From my login View Controller
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let tabVC = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
    let navVC = tabVC.viewControllers!.first as! UINavigationController
    let destVC = navVC.viewControllers.first as! CustomerMainViewController
    destVC.tempName = self.emailTextField.text!
}

@IBAction func loginButtonPresssed(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToTabBar", sender: self)
}
//From my View Controller (CustomerMainView Controller)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    username.text = self.tempName
}
```

I expect the username field on my view controller to be populated but it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. When you have multiple segue defined it could help to check for the segue identifier and/or safely unwrap the view controllers:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "GoToTabBar" {
        if let tabVC = segue.destination as? UITabBarController, 
            let navVC = tabVC.viewControllers?.first as? UINavigationController,
            let destVC = navVC.viewControllers.first as? CustomerMainViewController {
          destVC.tempName = self.emailTextField.text!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check with breakpoints that emailTextField.text is not nil, the prepare segue method is called, etc.?

Comment: yes.  the segue is called.  i'm not sure but perhaps its the fact that my segue is to the TabBarController, and then the TabBarController has relationship segue to the NavigationController, and the navigation controller has a rooviewcontroller relationship segue to the Customer Main View Controller.  Perhaps i've chosen the incorrect segues?

Comment: I figured it out.  The code above is correct I had another function being called overwriting the tempName.  DOH!  I'm good thanks for your help.